# Redirect WordPress login for customers but not admin

Tags: wp-admin, wp-redirect

I know how to redirect people from the /wp-login.php, however, I'm having an issue with excluding people who come from /wp-admin/ (which redirects to wp-login.php. Is there a way to exclude these? This is my current code:

```
function prevent_wp_login() {
    // WP tracks the current page - global the variable to access it
    global $pagenow;
    // Check if a $_GET['action'] is set, and if so, load it into $action variable
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    $args = (isset($_GET['args'])) ? $_GET['args'] : '';
    // Check if we're on the login page, and ensure the action is not 'logout'
    if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && ( ! $action || ( $action && ! in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'rp', 'resetpass')))) && ( ! $args || ( $args && ! in_array($args, array('reauth', 'redirect')))) ) {
        // Load the home page url
        // Redirect to the home page
        wp_redirect('/my-account/');
        // Stop execution to prevent the page loading for any reason
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thinking, I came up with a solution that allows wp-login.php to be redirected for the public/customers, but not for the admin. I did this by getting the referrer URL. Here is my updated code, but I'm open to other ideas.

```
//Redirect for login from wp-login.php to my-account if not admin
add_action('init', 'prevent_wp_login');
function prevent_wp_login() {
    // WP tracks the current page - global the variable to access it
    global $pagenow;
    // Check if a $_GET['action'] is set, and if so, load it into $action variable
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    
    //check if we came from the admin page or wp-admin
    $refer = urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    if (strpos($refer, 'wp-admin') !== false) {
        // stay on wp-login.php
    } else {
        // Check if we're on the login page, and ensure the action is not 'logout'
        if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && ( ! $action || ( $action && ! in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'rp', 'resetpass'))))) {
            // Load the home page url
            // Redirect to the home page
            wp_redirect('/my-account/');
            // Stop execution to prevent the page loading for any reason
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```